# Getting selected index from drop down list in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, drop-down-menu

Everything I've read online says this is the method and syntax I need to use to get the selected index from a drop down list.

```
var temp;
temp = document.getElementById("AdvOrBasicSearch_advSearch_ddlState").value;
var sState = temp.options[temp.selectedIndex].text;
```

However, I get the following error on the last line:

"Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'options' is null or not an object"

Below is a sampling of the drop down list (no need to post all 50 states)

```
<td><asp:dropdownlist id="ddlState" tabIndex="8" runat="server" EnableViewState="False" Width="150px"
    CssClass="clsTextInput">
    <asp:ListItem Value=""></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="AL">Alabama</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="AK">Alaska</asp:ListItem>
</asp:dropdownlist></td>
```

Comment: What does the actual rendered HTML look like? That would be much more useful seeing the script will also interact with that. It would show the actual rendered properties and so on.

Comment: I'm hoping "everything you've read online" didn't include the `.value` after the `getElementById()` call... :)

Comment: Where did you get the id `AdvOrBasicSearch_advSearch_ddlState` from?

Comment: I can barely read `asp` but this doesn't seem right: `temp = document.getElementById("AdvOrBasicSearch_advSearch_ddlState").value`.  If I had to take an educated guess, I'd drop the `.value`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to the comments I dropped the .value and everything works fine. Thx guys!

```
var temp;
temp = document.getElementById("AdvOrBasicSearch_advSearch_ddlState");
sState = temp.options[temp.selectedIndex].text;
```

Comment: I just came to the same in this fiddle: http://fiddle.jshell.net/RrNyV/ As a general side-note: If you have issues like that you can use `console.log(temp)` for example after populating the variable and check the console outputs in the browser debugging tools. Can save you a lot of headaches.